# Resuming the Linux Kernel Configuration

Tags: configuration, linux-kernel, development, configure

I am configuring a Linux kernel before I compile the code. However, after I was thirty minutes into answering the many questions concerning various kernel settings, I accidentally pressed Ctrl+C. I do not want to start over, so is it possible to make the configuration tool resume where I left off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to adjust the workflow a little bit, since configuring the Linux kernel from scratch is not for everyone (I'd almost say it's not for anybody). First, you are much better of with menu-based configurators like `make nconfig`, `make menuconfig` or the GUI based ones, as it usually allows you to save the configuration when you deem that a good idea. Second, unless you are really savvy about kernel things, you want to use some basic configuration as a starting point - either `make defconfig` or use your distribution as a base for your endeavours.

BTW, `make help` will tell you all the build targets (including the configuration ones, of which there is about dozen and a half) and the applicable options.

Answer (score 1):

If you were using menuconfig (xconfig, gconfig, nconfig), it would have only saved if you implicitly made it save.